# 日本語に違和感: 自分のプロフィール > 「票」タブ > N 件の票が入りました

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[image: N 件の票が入りました]

自分が入れた票を見る場所なので、「入りました」と受け身な表現はそぐわないと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 3件の投票